# How to correctly handle SOAP WS call with autogenerated and custom classes in Java?

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I am required to make a SOAP WS call. I autogenerated the classes using jaxws-maven-plugin, but the class it generated is very generic:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "docIn"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GrabaServicios")
public class GrabaServicios {

    protected GrabaServicios.DocIn docIn;

    public GrabaServicios.DocIn getDocIn() {
        return docIn;
    }

    public void setDocIn(GrabaServicios.DocIn value) {
        this.docIn = value;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "content"
    })
    public static class DocIn {

        @XmlMixed
        @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
        protected List<Object> content;

        public List<Object> getContent() {
            if (content == null) {
                content = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            return this.content;
        }

    }

}
```

In order to generate this docIn, I have implemented my own class:

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "Servicios")
@Data
public class Servicios {

    @XmlElement(name = "Envio")
    private List<Envio> envioList;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "uidcliente")
    private String uidCliente;

}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Data
public class Envio {

    @XmlElement(name = "Fecha")
    private String fecha;

    @XmlElement(name = "Servicio")
    private int servicio;

    @XmlElement(name = "Horario")
    private int horario;

    @XmlElement(name = "Bultos")
    private int bultos;

    @XmlElement(name = "Peso")
    private int peso;

    @XmlElement(name = "Portes")
    private String portes;

    @XmlElement(name = "Importes")
    private Importes importes;

    @XmlElement(name = "Remite")
    private Remite remite;

    @XmlElement(name = "Destinatario")
    private Destinatario destinatario;

    @XmlElement(name = "DevuelveAdicionales")
    private DevuelveAdicionales devuelveAdicionales;

}
```

What would be the correct way to handle this in Java? I managed to make the call by creating the XML in a more manual way, which I do not like:

```
Element body = doc.createElement("soapenv:Body");
envelope.appendChild(body);

Element grabaServicios = doc.createElement("asm:GrabaServicios");
body.appendChild(grabaServicios);

Element docIn = doc.createElement("asm:docIn");
grabaServicios.appendChild(docIn);
```

How can I use the auto-generated classes and my custom class to create the necessary XML and make the SOAP call? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.